# Lowercase letter L in R plot/expression

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, fonts, figure

I am trying to use the Computer Modern font when making a PDF with R. I have an expression that should contain a lowercase L. Since it looks so much like a 1, I would like to instead use ℓ. I have so far been incapable of doing this.

Minimal working example:

```
library(extrafont)
pdf("ell_plot.pdf", width=5.5, height=5, font="CM Roman")
plot(1, xlab="\u{2113}")
dev.off()
embed_fonts("ell_plot.pdf", outfile="ell_plot.pdf")
```

error message:

```
47: In text.default(x, y, ...) :
conversion failure on 'ℓ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e2>
```

and I just get "..." where there should be the \ell.

It shows up if I use cairo_pdf instead of pdf, but then Computer Modern doesn't work.

Comment: Try `xlab="\U2113"`

Comment: Check this article by `grid::`Paul Murrell: [Including fancy glyphs in R Graphics PDF output](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/PDF/pdfEncoding.html)

Comment: @Matt I still get "..."